# Creating a GUI using python that starts up the Node server.

Tags: windows, shell, qtgui

I have no idea how to do this, but I want to make a GUI application for Windows, using which I can start up a Node server placed inside an arbitrary folder. To do this using the command line, the process is simple, go to the directory and run 'npm start' or 'node app.js'. But how do I make a GUI which does the same?

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way to build a GUI that can do this is to use [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org).  You can show the GUI Window, get a button click, then run the command.  Take a look in the Cookbook and at the Demo programs. You'll find several examples that show "script launching".  It's going to be the quickest way to see something on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into this right away.